# Redirecting standard input of console application

Tags: c#, process, iostream, io-redirection

I have a console application which I'm trying to automate by redirecting Standard input stream of the process. In manual mode after opening the application, it waits for user input like below, [image]

I created the process with redirected Standard input stream.The code snippet is as follows,

```
Process newProcess = new Process();
newProcess.StartInfo.FileName = exeName;
newProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = argsLine;
newProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
newProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false ;
newProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
newProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
newProcess.Start();
```

But creating process like this gives an infinite loop shown below,
[image]

It's like I'm sending `Enter` key command continuously to the process input stream. Can anyone point me to what I'm doing wrong here?

Similarly, standard output stream redirection is also not working after making

> `newProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true`

But I can manage with that.

Does redirection of standard streams work with all console applications or is there any exception?

Comment: What does the code look like in the loop?

Comment: @Watson I don't have the code of the console application. It's a third party tool.

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here is a class I have written in order to handle that kind of stuff. Feel free to use it. Its purpose is to start a console application and "talk" to it. It has the ability to receive output as well. Good luck.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class ConsoleAppManager
{
    private readonly string appName;
    private readonly Process process = new Process();
    private readonly object theLock = new object();
    private SynchronizationContext context;
    private string pendingWriteData;

    public ConsoleAppManager(string appName)
    {
        this.appName = appName;

        this.process.StartInfo.FileName = this.appName;
        this.process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        this.process.StartInfo.StandardErrorEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

        this.process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        this.process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        this.process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        this.process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

        this.process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        this.process.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

        this.process.Exited += this.ProcessOnExited;
    }

    public event EventHandler<string> ErrorTextReceived;
    public event EventHandler ProcessExited;
    public event EventHandler<string> StandartTextReceived;

    public int ExitCode
    {
        get { return this.process.ExitCode; }
    }

    public bool Running
    {
        get; private set;
    }

    public void ExecuteAsync(params string[] args)
    {
        if (this.Running)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                "Process is still Running. Please wait for the process to complete.");
        }

        string arguments = string.Join(" ", args);

        this.process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;

        this.context = SynchronizationContext.Current;

        this.process.Start();
        this.Running = true;

        new Task(this.ReadOutputAsync).Start();
        new Task(this.WriteInputTask).Start();
        new Task(this.ReadOutputErrorAsync).Start();
    }

    public void Write(string data)
    {
        if (data == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        lock (this.theLock)
        {
            this.pendingWriteData = data;
        }
    }

    public void WriteLine(string data)
    {
        this.Write(data + Environment.NewLine);
    }

    protected virtual void OnErrorTextReceived(string e)
    {
        EventHandler<string> handler = this.ErrorTextReceived;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            if (this.context != null)
            {
                this.context.Post(delegate { handler(this, e); }, null);
            }
            else
            {
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnProcessExited()
    {
        EventHandler handler = this.ProcessExited;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnStandartTextReceived(string e)
    {
        EventHandler<string> handler = this.StandartTextReceived;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            if (this.context != null)
            {
                this.context.Post(delegate { handler(this, e); }, null);
            }
            else
            {
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }
    }

    private void ProcessOnExited(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        this.OnProcessExited();
    }

    private async void ReadOutputAsync()
    {
        var standart = new StringBuilder();
        var buff = new char[1024];
        int length;

        while (this.process.HasExited == false)
        {
            standart.Clear();

            length = await this.process.StandardOutput.ReadAsync(buff, 0, buff.Length);
            standart.Append(buff.SubArray(0, length));
            this.OnStandartTextReceived(standart.ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }

        this.Running = false;
    }

    private async void ReadOutputErrorAsync()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        do
        {
            sb.Clear();
            var buff = new char[1024];
            int length = await this.process.StandardError.ReadAsync(buff, 0, buff.Length);
            sb.Append(buff.SubArray(0, length));
            this.OnErrorTextReceived(sb.ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
        while (this.process.HasExited == false);
    }

    private async void WriteInputTask()
    {
        while (this.process.HasExited == false)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1);

            if (this.pendingWriteData != null)
            {
                await this.process.StandardInput.WriteLineAsync(this.pendingWriteData);
                await this.process.StandardInput.FlushAsync();

                lock (this.theLock)
                {
                    this.pendingWriteData = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.Since I'm using VS2010 I am not able to use async and await. :( I tried the code after editing and removing all async part(not sure it's correct) but I faced the same issue I explained in the question with the edited code too..

Comment: Are you sure that answer must include so much noise like regions and obvious xml comments?

Comment: Sorry about that it was copy pasted from a file that was formatted by stylecop.

Comment: I tried to use this via `var cam = new ConsoleAppManager("sudo"); cam.ExecuteAsync("apt install vim"); while (cam.Running) Thread.Sleep(1000);` but it didn't work (it hangs), am I missing something?

Comment: @Mihail Shishkov, it's very useful code. Please, could you explain, how to rewrite this code for .net 3.5 (without class Threading.Tasks)?

Comment: @neo OK, I will add the 3.5 version may be tomorrow when I have the time.

Answer (score 9):

Following the previous answer, I'll just add the extension method of SubArray, just in case *add this class to your code where it's not nested inside any class* ( the code didn't look readable in a comment, so I added it here )

```
public static class CharArrayExtensions
{
    public static char[] SubArray(this char[] input,int startIndex, int length)
    {
        List<char> result= new List<char>();
        for (int i = startIndex; i < length; i++)
        {
            result.Add(input[i]);
        }

        return result.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the ConsoleAppManager, it works well but I have to mention that the same effect for capturing output and error messages could be achieved using events found in the `Process` class:`OutputDataReceived` and `ErrorDataReceived` and call `BeginOutputReadLine()` and `BeginErrorReadLine()` after starting the process.

Also that `WriteInputTask()` is killing the CPU, might want to use some sort of `ResetEvent` between the while loop and setting of `pendingWriteData` or send the input directly to the process.