# How do I run another cmd.exe call inside a Console application?

Tags: c#, cmd, console, chocolatey

I am writing a C# Console App and I need to install dependencies using Chocolatey and then set up some config. The problem is I want to do all of these tasks in one Console. However, the below code example pops up a new Console window.

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    // do some stuff
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/C choco install nssm");
    // do other stuff
}
```

Is there any way I can do the setup part as a part of this console application?

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: @Yacoub it opens a new console to download from chocolatey

Answer (score 3):

You can use [another override](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb(v=vs.110).aspx) of the `Process.Start` method that accepts a `ProcessStartInfo` argument. This class has a `WindowStyle` property that you can set to `ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden`. This will make whatever window created by the process be hidden.

```
ProcessStartInfo process_start_info = new ProcessStartInfo();

process_start_info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

process_start_info.FileName = @"C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\choco.exe";

process_start_info.Arguments = "install googlechrome";

var process = Process.Start(process_start_info);

process.WaitForExit();
```

Please note that I am executing choco.exe directly instead of executing the cmd.exe. But if you are able to use cmd.exe then this should not be an issue.

Please note also that I am storing the result of invoking `Process.Start` into a variable and then I am using the `WaitForExit` method to wait for the process to finish. After that you can simply start a new process to install a new package using similar code. You can encapsulate this functionality into some method and use it multiple times.

Comment: Well, that could be helpful but in this case it's not gonna work since you need to choose a couple of options during the installation through Chocolatey

Comment: @Hooman, you can redirect input and output between you and the process that you create. Here is a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21848271/redirecting-standard-input-of-console-application

Comment: You can definitely do this kind of stuff. Another consideration you can do is to use the chocolatey.lib instead to install Chocolatey packages.