# Redirecting standard output of console application

Tags: c#, class, events, process, io-redirection

I have problems using the class from
[Redirecting standard input of console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21848271/redirecting-standard-input-of-console-application)

I can execute the Console Application

```
var proc = new ConsoleAppManager("calc.exe");
proc.ExecuteAsync();
```

but how can I receive the output from the Console Application? I think I have to use the StandartTextReceived Event but I do not know how exactly. Can somebody give me a sample code for receiving the output in a RichTextBox?

Comment: Side note:  Default Windows Calc.exe is not console application

Comment: It is not the default Windows calc.exe

Comment: is that richtextbox in a WPF or in a WinForm app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You indeed need to subscribe to that `StandartTextReceived` Event. Here is an example how you can do that from a button_click event:

```
// class member on the form
ConsoleAppManager cm = null;    

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // check if have an instance, to prevent starting too much
    if (cm == null)
    {
        cm = new ConsoleAppManager(@"cmd.exe");
    } else
    {
        if (cm.Running)
        {
            // still running, bail out
            return; 
        }
    }
    // subscribe to the event
    // the implementation of the ConsoleAppManager handles UI thread sync
    cm.StandartTextReceived += (s, text) =>
    {
        // it doesn't play nicely if the form
        // closes while the process is still running
        if (!this.richTextBox1.IsDisposed)
        {
            this.richTextBox1.AppendText(text);
        }
    };
    cm.ExecuteAsync(@"/c ""dir c:\*.exe /s """);
}

// it is very limited to end it ...
private void Form3_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    if (cm != null)
    {
        // how on earth do you end that process?
        cm = null; 
    }
}
```