# Connecting C# SerialPort to Hyper-V named pipe (Just Like PuTTy can)

Tags: c#, linux, serial-port, hyper-v

I am working on an Application to Connect to virtual machines(using Hyper-V).
(I am using Virtual Machines now for Development, but the end-product will be physical Serial Connected Machines. not VM's)
I have created a named pipe with the COM adaptor like this.

[image: Creating the Named Pipe in Hyper-V]

I am able to connect with PuTTy Like so.

[image: Connection Information for PuTTy]

Running a CentOS Build on the Hyper-V

[image: Custom CentOS Terminal]

I then wrote a simple Application to connect to it with C#

```
my_Serial_Port = new SerialPort();
my_Serial_Port.PortName = @"\\.\pipe\ttyS0";
my_Serial_Port.BaudRate = m_BaudRate;
my_Serial_Port.DataBits = 8;
my_Serial_Port.Parity = Parity.None;
my_Serial_Port.StopBits = StopBits.One;
my_Serial_Port.Handshake = Handshake.None;
my_Serial_Port.DtrEnable = true;
my_Serial_Port.RtsEnable = true;
my_Serial_Port.WriteTimeout = 15000;
my_Serial_Port.ReadTimeout = 15000;

my_Serial_Port.ErrorReceived += my_Serial_Port_ErrorReceived;
```

The thing is when I open the connection, I get this Exception thrown.

[image: Parameter Portname Cannot Start with /]

A little searching, and I found this information but no work-around.
[msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.portname](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.portname(v=vs.110).aspx)
I have also Tried running my application as Administrator (Putty Needed this too)
And it did not work.

With  Oystein's Suggestion I tried:

```
string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

string result = "The following serial ports were found:" + Environment.NewLine;

// Display each port name to the console.
foreach (string port in ports)
{
    result += port + Environment.NewLine;
}

MessageBox.Show(result);
```

Unfortunately COM1 is on the Physical Machine.

[image: Only Found COM1]

Does any one know how I can get this to work?
Thanks!

Comment: Try using SerialPort.GetPortNames (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.getportnames(v=vs.110).aspx) to find what format the application sees the serialports as.

Comment: Unfortunately it only Lists, COM1.

Comment: I have also ran the Command in the PowerShell
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> [System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles("\\.\\pipe\\")
And can confirm that the pipe is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Automate PuTTy Connections with PLink.

I read on another website this Answer.
USE [Plink](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.70/htmldoc/Chapter7.html)

There is a plus side to this solution.
I will be able to automate Serial and SSH connections with the same tool/wrapper.
Using functions like

```
"Send_Command(string command);"
```

and

```
"Wait_For_Prompt(string prompt, int timeout);"
```

I found this on Stack Overflow, which helped me to complete the project.
[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21848271/redirecting-standard-input-of-console-application)

Additionnally, PLink comes with the full install of Putty, and more usefull applications if you look where you installed it.

- pageant.exe
- plink.exe
- pscp.exe (windows to linux File transfer)
- psftp.exe

Answer (score 0):

Hyper-V connects virtual COM port on guest to Win32 named pipe on Host. On host you should connect to named pipe ([NamedPipeClientStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.namedpipeclientstream)), not serial port.